# Why cant i use both test artifacts in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

Why do i need to choose between **Unit tests** and **Android instrumentation tests**?

Why cant i have both at the same time?

The code for testing is located in different places:

- `src/test/java/{package name}` for `JUnit` tests
- `src/androidTest/java/{package name}` for android specific tests

After choosing one artifact - the project's structure changes and one of the above java folders become green.

Can someone please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AndroidStudio different test scopes are just different [flavors](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants).

Selecting test artifact tells IDE witch flavor is test scope and because IntelliJ IDEA (on which AndroidStudio is based) does not support multiple test scopes in same module, we need to select them manually.

According to [What's New in Android Development Tools](https://youtu.be/f7ihSQ44WO0?t=2575) video from Google IO 2015. Android development tools team is working on this issue.